# Arithmetic mistakes when dealing with large numbers in java

Tags: java, numbers

I'm working with some arithmetic operations in Java which need to process very large numbers.

See this simple code snippet:

```
// A = a^k mod p 

    double k = 96 , a = 13 , p = 353 ;
    double A = (Math.pow(a,k))%p;
    System.out.println(A);
```

This prints 29.0.

When I use my windows calculator, it returns 58.0 for (13^96) % 353.
I know that the calculator is correct.

Why does this Java code print an incorrect result?

Comment: Use BigDecimal instead.. 13^96 would overflow the range supported by double

Comment: @SMA Overflow is not the issue, “only” precission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calcul `13^96` result in the number :

```
86808413954902578113899124146033582025796522106191700214004730205740649831517648547259748010923363334343041
```

which requires too much precision to be stored in a `double` type

---

You can do this with `BigInteger` :

```
BigInteger bK = new BigInteger("96");
BigInteger bA = new BigInteger("13");
BigInteger bP = new BigInteger("353");
BigInteger res = bA.modPow(bK, bP);    // same as  res = bA.pow(96).mod(bP);
System.out.println(res);               // 58
```

Comment: if 96 is a varibal like a=96 can I make it like this : BigInteger bK = new BigInteger("a");

Comment: @BaraDos Seriously ? You cannot wait some time and think I'm here only for you ? I let you work a bit on Java, because `"a"` is a String
`String a = 96; new BigInteger(a); ` OR `long a = 96; BigInteger.valueOf(a)` si right

Answer (score 3):

## Explanation

Well, `Math.pow` probably does not do what you think it does. This is not your fault, it's practically lying to you. It returns a `double` that is *reasonably close* to 13^96, but not exactly. Since we are talking a number around 10^107 here, a small relative change means an absolute change far larger than 353. So, all bets about this are off.

### Example

To put more numbers to this, practically the same problem arises when we use decimal scientific notation: The quotient is [practically one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13%5E96+%2F+8.68084139549026*10%5E106) but the difference is [around 2^91](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13%5E96+-+868084139549026*10%5E92).
In general, floating *point* numbers are unsuitable for integer arithmetic, you are practically bound to get these problems.

## Solution

While a big integer lib would work, there is a more grounded way to approach this: Perform [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_exponentiation) and take the modulus each step.
In case you're a beginner, this will teach you more than the black box of some big int lib.